To know some type of people are kafir or not?
Assalamu alaikum brother. How are those people who speaks about tawhidi people specially salafi as fundamentalist although they give their identity as Muslim. Are they kafir?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&Asite about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

"Fundamentalist" has taken on a somewhat derogatory meaning in modern parlance, but really it just means someone who takes a strict, mostly literal, interpretation of the scriptures.
This is an accurate representation of many (most? all?) Muslims who identify as Salafi; they rely on the fundamentals of what was known and was without doubt during the time of the prophet and the earliest generations, rather than relying on the spurious interpretations that evolved over time.
While the term is accurate, as mentioned above it has taken on a derogatory meaning and is often used as an insult rather than as a simple descriptor. Denigrating and deriding other Muslims is definitely against Allah's command as He says:

11 O you who have believed, let not a people ridicule people; perhaps they may be better than them; nor let women ridicule women; perhaps they may be better than them. And do not insult one another and do not call each other by nicknames. Wretched is the name of disobedience after faith. And whoever does not repent - then it is those who are the wrongdoers.
— Al-Hujurat 11

However, when used to describe the particular method by which Salafi and other such groups differ from other more liberal interpretations, without dismissing their status as Muslims, this is fine.
For a better idea of what does and does not constitute kufr, see also: Is "X" kufr
